# Визуализация архитектуры проекта ПОСЛЕ проектирования

Tags: проектирование, uml, визуализация

Добрый день, я разрабатываю архитектуру на UML для моей программы и пока мне очень нравится этот инструмент, т.к. он помогает компактно визуализировать систему. Но как визуализировать проект после его написания, когда изменения рациональней проводить непосредственно в коде, чем в UML-диаграммах?

Я мог бы перед внесением изменений в код внести соответствующие изменения в UML-диаграмму, но такое подход превращает UML в "пятую ногу", ИМХО.

Как вносить изменения в проект и при этом продолжать видеть всю картину целиком? Может ли потребность в визуализации быть следствием от недостатка опыта в программировании?

Comment: Использовать инструменты строящие UML по коду. НЕ пытаться детализировать в UML все.

Comment: Такие инструменты есть не для всех языков. Например, сигналы и слоты Qt нельзя нормально представить в виде UML-диаграммы классов. А я как раз использую Qt. Еще скажите пожалуйста, как называются инструменты преобразующие код в диаграммы?